# How do I Auto-kill process on OS X as they spawn?

Tags: macos

My IT department has decided to spam everyone with annoying notifications. It seems like the just schedule a program to run every X number of mins and notify me of "blah" if necessary.

How can I detect and kill the running of the process automatically?

I'm running 10.6

Comment: For some reason this brings back memories of hacking the library's computers when they first got them to go to sites other than their catalog.

Comment: Complain to the IT department. Encourage your colleagues to do the same. Copy your supervisor on the complaint and make it clear that the IT department's new policy is interfering with your work. As you've described it, the policy doesn't sound all that bad — it's good to notify people of necessary things. Perhaps the problem is just that the determination of "necessary" isn't being calculated correctly, or someone has an inflated idea of what's really necessary that needs to be toned down.

Comment: if you know where the process is in the filesystem which they start you could just replace it with some noop shell script or even better with a folder named exactly as the process files...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while [true];
do
   kill -9 `ps -ef|grep 'unique info'|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`
   sleep 10
done
```

Comment: More efficiently: `kill -9 \`ps -ef | awk '$2 == PROCINFO["pid"] {next} /unique info/ {print $2}'\``

Comment: @Rob - after typing the first version for 30 years, I'll probably not remember yours; but, it's certainly cleaner.

Comment: Even more efficiently, and simpler `pkill -9 processname`